# What is the smallest value of n such that an algorithm whose running time is 100n^2 runs faster than an algorithm whose running time is 2^n?

Tags: algorithm

What is the smallest value of n such that an algorithm whose running time is 100n^2 runs faster than an algorithm whose running time is 2^n on the same machine?

**The Scope**
Although I am interested in the answer, I am more interested in how to find the answer step by step (so that I can repeat the process to compare any two given algorithms if at all possible).

From the MIT Press Algorithms book

Comment: It is conceivably bigger than the value `m` with `100m² = 2m`, which might remind of `100m² - 2m = 0`.

Comment: Why would you down-vote this question? The question is in the freaking MIT book. wow...

Comment: Who is the `you` above? One (mis-?)feature of stackexchange is that neither up-, nor downvoting requires comments, and there is no connecting votes to comments if the comment's text doesn't claim one (speaking of which: no vote from me).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you check your question and tell us whether it is actually the question you wanted to ask. The "2n" looks very suspicious because your question doesn't make sense. There is no integer where 100n^2 < 2n.

Comment: Astute observation gnasher, the correct question is 100n^2 < 2^n. Thanks for catching that

Comment: The downvoting is neither lunatic nor trolling: it is assistance in earning another badge.

Comment: @greybeard please look at the history of what I rolled back. It had been vandalized.

Comment: @greybeard I see what you mean. So, that was obviously - or at minimum, arguably - a tiny mistake, rolling back to 2 instead of 3. In the future, try to assume the best intentions, instead of assuming someone was being "unfair"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the values of `n` where 100 × n<sup>2</sup> is less than 2 × n.

Which is the solution of 100 × n<sup>2</sup> - 2 × n < 0, which happens to be `0 < n < 0.02`.

One thousand words:

[image]

EDIT:

The original question talked about 2 × n, not 2<sup>n</sup> (see comments).

For 2<sup>n</sup>, head to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182156/multiplying-exponents-solving-for-n

Answer is 15

Comment: Yeah I figured it was something along those lines until Mr. "so always" provided a nice little headache for me. Wasn't sure what happened there for a minute (lol). Thanks.

Comment: A picture is 1000 words right, lol. What did you use to generate that nice little graphic if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: @NateNeuhaus gnu octave.

Comment: But the question asks to calculate for 2^n, and not 2n :)
Still a pretty neat answer. Thank you @axiom

Comment: was asking 2^n. And for n positive integer.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you have to know, is what running time means. If we're talking about algorithms theoretically, the running time of an algorithm is the number of steps (or the amount of time) it takes to finish *depending on the size of the input* (where the size of the input is for example the number of bits, but also other measures are sometimes considered). In this sense, the algorithm which requires the least number of steps is the fastest.

So in your two formulas, n is the size of the input, and 100 * n^2 and 2^n are the number of steps the two algorithms run if given an input of size n.

On first sight, the 2^n algorithm looks much faster than the 100 * n^2 algorithm. For example, for n = 4, 100*4^2 = 1600 and 2^4 = 16.

However, 2^n is an *exponential function*, whereas 100 * n^2 is a *polynomial function*. That means that when n is large enough, it will be the case that 2^n > 100 * n^2. So you will have to solve the unequality 100 * n^2 < 2^n. This will already be the case for a fairly small n, so you can just start evaluating the functions, starting at n=5, and you will reach the answer to the question in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however this question was about the practice not theory. At this point I'm working on the exercises through the first and second chapters on the book and wasn't quite sure of my answer. As far the math goes, I am aware that the growth rate of an exponential function will grow much faster than a linear function. But thank you for your time.

Comment: If you're doing "algorithms", as opposed to, say, "programming in c++", you're doing theory, not practice. Note that the question was rollbacked to the wrong version (a linear function 2n does not make much sense in this context), and that the answer you accepted answers this wrong question. (I just started here and do not have enough reputation yet to do anything about it, or to comment on the wrong answer.)

Comment: Well I am doing algorithms... (wait for it) in C++! Hows that for some practice on my theories, or is that I am practicing but only in theory, Watson?

Comment: @Hoopje Thanks indeed for your contribution. Are you an academic? Last time I found more than 10 sentences to say "You have to do it by brute force." the author was a famous professor!